# Source code of getcontext and setcontext

Tags: system-calls, libc

I have been trying to explore the source code of the getcontext() and setcontext functions but I have not been able to spot the right file or resource. Any help in this regard will be helpful.

I was able to trace to http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.14.1/setcontext_8c_source.html but there is no info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you found it difficult to find the source code is that `getcontext` and `setcontext` are (generally?) **implemented in assembly** than in C. Here are the source codes

[setcontext](http://www.koders.com/noncode/fid466DE9347BF79B388783D3F5D94BAF6748F618C9.aspx?s=readdir64) and [getcontext](http://www.koders.com/noncode/fid62EE9446C4DEED004E74CD6D61D7C81435E413FE.aspx?s=queue)

However, these assembly codes are not so easy to read. I think `man getcontext` is better. Anyways, good luck :)